# Visual Studio 2013 ulitmate update 5 installation error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am getting the below error while installing update 5 on visual studio 2013  ultimate:

[image]

I have tried following:
1) Disabling AVG.
2) Full install of 2013, i.e checking all checkbox while installation.

Any thouhts?? Currently i have visual studio 2013 ultimate with update 2 installed. 
Thank you.

Comment: What version of windows are you running?

Comment: @GustavRasmussen  Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by nstalling visual studio 2013 ultimate with update 4.  Instead of updating with update seperately.  Thanks you.